# Xcode 4 rich text not working.

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2, richtext

I have Xcode 4.2. At some point the rich text just stopped working. The only elements that it is selecting are strings, comments and number values. The rest is just written in white (I'm using the Midnight option).

I've tried restarting my machine, Xcode and changing my preferences (to Low Key and then back to Midnight). This only is happening on one project and not the others. Any ideas on how to correct this? It is surprising how this makes coding a bit more strenuous on the eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

Go to `Organizer` --> `Projects` --> `YourRichTextFailingProject` --> then hit the button `Delete` under `Derived Data`.